# ¿como redigir a otra pagina si la url no existe en laravel 10?

Tags: laravel, rutas

Hola tengo una duda que no logro resolver eh creado un pequeño crud en Laravel 10. Eh definido una ruta para editar registros entonces tengo esto:

```
Route::resource('/users', UserController::class)->names('users');
```

cuando voy a editar un registro me tira una url del estilo:
`/users/4/edit`
ahora si por ejemplo yo ingreso cambio la url a algo como
`/users/4/` o
`/users/edit`
me muestra una pagina en blanco como haria para mostrar la tipica pagina 404 o simplemente redirigir a otra ya que dichas url no existen. Por mas que eh buscado no encuentro como hacerlo.

Eh probado con esto

```
Route::any('/{any}', function () {
    return redirect('/pagina-de-error');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Pero no eh conseguido nada.
Actualizacion en web.php tengo:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/


Route::resource('/users', UserController::class)->names('users');
Route::resource('users', UserController::class)
        ->missing(function (Request $request) {
            return Redirect::route('users.index');
        });
```

Comment: No es necesaria la primera llamada a resource, aparte debe ser ->name, no ->names, esa primera parte la puedes borrar

Comment: si pongo name en lugar de names me da error

Comment: Si, pero esa linea la tenes que borrar, no es necesaria

Comment: Entiendo aun que igual sigo en el mismo dilema.

Answer (score 0):

Podés adaptar el comportamiento normal de Laravel en este sentido, con el metodo missing, de la siguiente forma;

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PhotoController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

// al encontrar una ruta no especificada cae en el Fallback    
Route::fallback(function () {
   return abort(404);
});

Route::resource('users', UserController::class)
        ->missing(function (Request $request) {
            return Redirect::route('users.index');
        });
```

En este caso, ante una ruta desconocida, irá al index de Users

Comment: gracias por la respuesta. Sigo igual ya que probando tu recomendación entra a la url aunque no existe me muestra solo una pagina en blanco. En lugar de redirigir al index

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar como tienes todo tu archivo web.php?

Comment: actualize la pregunta poniendo lo que tengo en web.php

Comment: Allí agregué el Fallback, ¿puedes probar con eso?

Comment: pues no sigo igual. Solo veo que al poner esto en el metodo show si me muestra la tipica pagina de error. Pero no estoy seguro de si es correcto hacer esto.
`public function show($id)
    {
        return abort(404);
      }`

Comment: Pero por qué mostrarías el abort dentro del show?, de todas formas lo que necesitas es que te muestre una pagina de error 404?

Comment: no necesito mostrar nada en el show solo que probando me di cuenta de eso. Lo unico que quiero es que redirija a otra pagina cuando en edit a alguien se le ocurra jugar con la url o como bien mencionas la pagina de error pero no lo eh conseguido. Solo me muestra una pagina en blanco

Comment: Ahi hice un ajuste mas, puedes probarlo asi tal cual, reemplazando lo que tienes en tu web.php

Answer (score 0):

Puedes redirigir a otra página si la ruta a la que intentas acceder no existe utilizando el middleware RedirectIfNotFound. Este middleware te permite verificar si una ruta existe y, en caso contrario, redirigir al usuario a una página específica.

Primero crear un nuevo middleware Ejemplo

```
php artisan make:middleware RedirectIfNotFound
```

Dentro del método handle, verifica si la ruta existe utilizando el método Route::has() de Laravel. Si la ruta no existe, realiza la redirección utilizando el método redirect():

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Route::has($request->route()->getName())) {
        return redirect()->route('ruta_redireccion'); // Reemplaza 'ruta_redireccion' con el nombre de la ruta a la que quieres redirigir
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Abre el archivo app/Http/Kernel.php y registra el middleware en el arreglo $routeMiddleware:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
'redirectIfNotFound' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfNotFound::class,
```

];

Ahora, puedes aplicar el middleware redirectIfNotFound a las rutas a las que deseas verificar si existen. Por ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/mi-ruta', 'MiControlador@miMetodo')->middleware('redirectIfNotFound');
```

Por último, define la ruta de redirección en tu archivo routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/ruta-redireccion', function () {
return view('pagina_redireccion'); // Reemplaza 'pagina_redireccion' con la vista o ruta a la que deseas redirigir
})->name('ruta_redireccion');
```